# SignalR Initialization Issue On Different Computers

Tags: javascript, jquery, signalr

I have SignalR working fine on my main PC, but when I move my project over to my laptop and try to run it, SignalR is throwing the error below in the console.

```
 Error: No transport could be initialized successfully. Try specifying a different transport or none at all for auto initialization.
```

I have tried using different versions to no avail(2.2, 2.1.2, 2.0.3).

I have researched the error, but none of the solutions seem to relate to why the error would only happen on one PC. Any ideas?

Here is the full log for signalR:

```
[11:49:30 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to 
hub 'tcardhub'.jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js:81 [11:49:30 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.4&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22tcardhub%22%7D%5D'.   
SignalRHubService.js:60 Error: No transport could be initialized successfully. Try specifying a different transport or none at all for auto initialization.
    at Object.signalR._.error (http://localhost:29858/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js:178:21)
    at signalR.fn.signalR.start.initialize (http://localhost:29858/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js:553:50)
    at Object.signalR.fn.signalR.start.connection._.negotiateRequest.signalR.transports._logic.ajax.success (http://localhost:29858/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js:765:21)
    at n.Callbacks.j (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:2:26911)
    at Object.n.Callbacks.k.fireWith [as resolveWith] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:2:27724)
    at x (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:4:11065)
    at XMLHttpRequest.n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send.b (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js:4:14577)Hub.errorHandler @ SignalRHubService.js:60(anonymous function) @ jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js:836n.event.dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3n.event.add.r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3n.event.trigger @ jquery.min.js:3e.event.trigger @ jquery-migrate.min.js:2n.fn.extend.triggerHandler @ jquery.min.js:3signalR.fn.signalR.start.initialize @ jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js:558signalR.fn.signalR.start.connection._.negotiateRequest.signalR.transports._logic.ajax.success @ jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js:765n.Callbacks.j @ jquery.min.js:2n.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2x @ jquery.min.js:4n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send.b @ jquery.min.js:4
jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js:81 [11:49:30 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)] SignalR: Stopping connection.
jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js:81 [11:49:30 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'tcardhub'.
jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js:81 [11:49:30 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=U6E4eibrnyXgS%2FJWuNo5iwIy%2BU8S6x1w9Vh%2FDmthMMvFCw8g%2BX53Fq9f%2FlNdqyJIOW0j7uk8sZ4BwN4uP52QwpFNMjZJDUdZ2ZjeXLgSvSLUZmQ3L9fZLXYatHcs0bh2&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22tcardhub%22%7D%5D'.
jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js:81 [11:49:30 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://localhost:29858/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&clientPro…2Bxa%2Fe2uZd4&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22tcardhub%22%7D%5D&tid=8'.
jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js:81 [11:49:30 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)] SignalR: EventSource connected.
jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js:81 [11:49:30 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents transport selected. Initiating start request.
jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js:81 [11:49:30 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)] SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.
jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js:81 [11:49:30 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)] SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332 and a connection lost timeout of 20000.
```

The error happens in IE and Chrome. I am using a work laptop with higher security, so I am thinking it might be possible that there is some security setting that is breaking things.

Comment: It seems like your browser doesn't work with WebSockets (I assume you haven't changed the transport options). Try with another browser.

Also,  add this line of code in the client and open the console in the browser : `            $.connection.hub.logging = true;` in order to have some idea what is happening

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I updated the post with the full log.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by changing my transport to "auto" instead of using "webSockets". I don't know why web sockets doesn't work on one computer, but at least this fixed it for now.

Comment: Maybe you were connecting where websockets were not enabled or are even not supported (Win2K8/Win7)

Comment: Are web sockets really not enabled on Win7? I was using windows 8 on the machine where it worked. That would be good to know. Thanks.

Comment: Win7 does not natively support websockets at all - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039438/using-websocket-on-windows7